# How to reset combinelatest after subscribe

Tags: rxjs, observable

My requirement in rxJs is,
how to reset combinelatest after subscribing the data.

after subscribing the result, the subscription again need to call only all the observable get modified (all the combinelatest parameter). and not for any one of the parameter modified.

```
Observable.combineLatest(
      this.one$,
      this.two$,
      this.three$,
      this.four$,
      this.five$
    ).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Can you please include desired output? It's not clear what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 4):

I think you need the zip operator.

```
zip(
  this.one$,
  this.two$,
  this.three$,
  this.four$,
  this.five$
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
},
err => console.error(err));
```